# Use Match and then Replace in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider:

```
    <% 
        content = ""+Request.Form("completehtml")+"";
        contentmatch = content;
        contentmatch = contentmatch.match(/(<div class="content">[\s\S]+?)(?=[##])/ig); 
    %>
```

If I get the above match and it gives me some HTML: is it possible to find text in the match and to replace it again?

```
    contentmatch = contentmatch.replace(/test/ig, 'working');
```

The problem I get with the replace is, that Internet Explorer says it is not supported. What is the reason?

```
    <% 
        content = ""+Request.Form("completehtml")+"";
        contentmatch = content;
        contentmatch = contentmatch.replace(/>\s+?</ig, '><'); 
        contentmatch = contentmatch.match(/(<div class="content">[\s\S]+?)(?=[##])/ig); 
    %>
```

OK it seems like I figured it out partly - If you do the replace before the match it seems to work, if you do it after the match is does not seem to work.

Is it possible to do a replace after the match?

Comment: Reg3x cann0t pärse HtM|_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: "The problem I get with the replace is, that IE says it is not supported?" --> IS THAT WORKS WITH MOZILLA FIREFOX ???

Comment: Mark Byers - Nice one :-) but it can parse simple html if you are sure the code validates if <p></p> is always going to be <p></p> you can parse it - I think the trick is not to parse complicated html that does not validate.... but I am using the regex on my own stuff which is not over complicated and always validates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
contentmatch = contentmatch.match(/(<div class="content">[\s\S]+?)(?=[##])/ig);
```

is replacing the contentmatch variable with the result of the match method. That result is an Array. Arrays do happen to have a replace method (in FF), but it does something different than the String method, which is what you want.